# Writing subscripts in editorialmanager abstract window

Tags: paper-submission

I am trying to submit a manuscript to a journal that uses [editorialmanager](http://www.ariessys.com/software/editorial-manager/) system. I wish to know how to insert subscripts in the abstract window [image]. When I go to insert special characters link [image]

I only find subscripts for the numbers from 0 to 9. How to write subscripts of letters like

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: What comes out when you select a numerical subscript?

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano It just writes the number as a subscript.

Comment: Usually the abstract field in this kind of electronic submission systems is not meant to support complex formats. Some support the html `<sub>` tag. You can try it, but if it doesn't work I suggest you to simply write in plain text, like "NL".

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Actually, I tried the <sub> tag but it did not work. I might write it as plain text. Thanks.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I found that you can write the capital letters in small size for example the html code for the capital letter L written in small size is "&#671;" without the quotation marks. It is not a subscript, but it is closest possible thing that I could found.